# When will Allegiant open its schedule for December 2018?

Tags: allegiant-air

I'm trying to book for Thanksgiving, but they are not showing that far in advance.  I emailed the company but didn't get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just looked at the Allegiant website. When entering a flight request, this text appears at the bottom of the window:

[image]

If tomorrow the Nov. 6 date has changed to Nov. 7, you'll have your answer.